How to pass data inside itemBuilder when building ListView?
How to pass data inside buildListItem function as a parameter?
When I add a third parameter data to buildListItem, it gives an error in the IDE:

The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type
'Widget? Function(BuildContext, int)'.

final List<RapportData> data = snapshot.data!;

return ListView.separated(
  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: data.length,
  itemBuilder: buildListItem, // how to pass `data`?
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
);

Widget buildListItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      var rapportData = data[index]; //data is not avalable here
      onTapFunction(context, Group(rapportData));
    },
    child: ListTile(...
    
    ... 
}


You can try pass parameter like this:
final List<RapportData> data = snapshot.data!;

return ListView.separated(
  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildListItem(context, data[index]),
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
);

Widget buildListItem(BuildContext context, RapportData rapportData) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      //rapportData can use here
      onTapFunction(context, Group(rapportData));
    },
    child: ListTile(...
    
    ... 
}

